# Google My Business API Returns 200 Status But Empty JSON Response

Tags: python, google-api, google-oauth, google-my-business-api, google-my-business

I'm using the Google My Business API in my project to fetch insights using the `reportInsights` method. The Python script iterates over the list of locations and fetches insights for each location. I know the code works because the majority of the locations return insights perfectly.

However, for some locations the API returns a 200 status code but an empty JSON response body. No error message of any kind is provided.

Things I've already checked:

- The oAuth tokens are valid and not expired
- The locations show up as `verified` in the Business Profile dashboard.
- The locations do have insights data for the selected timeframe in the Business Profile dashboard.
- The account itself is most likely not the problem. Every account I tested had at least one location that successfully returns data.

I'd appreciate any advice or insight into the issue.

Comment: Is the JSON empty; or is the "locationNames" array inside JSON empty? By the way, what is the code that you wrote for that purpose; it can give some insights about your work.

Comment: @captainsham is this issue fixed?